# Is there a way to use latex expression of chemarr for `gitbook` format of bookdown package?

Tags: r, latex, mathjax, bookdown, gitbook

I would like to use latex expression of chemarr for `gitbook` format of bookdown package.

```latex
\begin{equation}
  [C] + [R] 
  \xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{k_1}
  [CR] + [C] 
  \xrightleftharpoons[k_{-2}]{k_2}
  [C2R]
(\#eq:multiplebinding)
\end{equation}
```

For PDF format, there is no problem of displaying the equation.

[image: PDF-latex]

On the other hand, for gitbook format there is an error message.

[image: gitbook-latex]

It's mainly because I cannot define the following yaml header for `gitbook` format.

```yaml
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{chemarr}
```

Is there a way to use latex expression of chemarr for `gitbook` format of bookdown package? If it's impossible, is there a way to use `include_graphics` function and add equation numbering (say, 19.16 in this example)?

Comment: I don't have enough time to help you here, but this might help: https://github.com/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/issues/217

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yihui Xie already gave a good hint to the solution:

Put this code into your document (where you want the equation to appear):

```
$$
\require{mhchem}
\begin{equation}
  [C] + [R] 
  \xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{k_1}
  [CR] + [C] 
  \xrightleftharpoons[k_{-2}]{k_2}
  [C2R]
(\#eq:multiplebinding)
\end{equation}
$$
```

Needs to use the arrow of `mhchem` instead of `chemarr` since only the first is part of MathJax. But I think it should anyway be basically the same.

This method should work for all Latex commands supported by MathJax (http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, Steffen. This is the perfect answer.

Comment: @SungpilHan I'm still waiting for you to offer your bounty so that I can start to offer mine :)